# Create Windows User Profile with netUserAdd function

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I've implemented a code using NetUserAdd function ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) which create a Windows User Profile after running it. I run it in Visual Studio 2008 (Visual Studio Compiler) and worked properly. Now I need to run it with mingw compiler (in Qt or CodeBlocks) but every time I try to compile it I get following error in both Qt or CodeBlocks:

undefined reference to 'NetUserAdd@16'

below is the code I used it to create a user profile in windows.

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <lm.h>

int addUserFunc(int argc)
{
   USER_INFO_1 ui;
   DWORD dwLevel = 1;
   DWORD dwError = 0;
   NET_API_STATUS nStatus;

   char uText[] = "TestUser";
   wchar_t wText[20];
   mbstowcs(wText, uText, strlen(uText)+1);//Plus null
   LPWSTR uName = wText;

   char pText[] = "123456";
   mbstowcs(wText, pText, strlen(pText)+1);//Plus null
   LPWSTR passWord = wText;

   if (argc != 3)
   {
       fwprintf(stderr, L"Usage: %s \\\\ServerName UserName\n", L"USER");
      exit(1);
   }

   ui.usri1_name = uName;
   ui.usri1_password = passWord;
   ui.usri1_priv = USER_PRIV_USER;
   ui.usri1_home_dir = NULL;
   ui.usri1_comment = NULL;
   ui.usri1_flags = UF_SCRIPT;
   ui.usri1_script_path = NULL;

   nStatus = NetUserAdd(NULL,
                    dwLevel,
                    (LPBYTE)&ui,
                    &dwError);
   if (nStatus == NERR_Success)
      fwprintf(stderr, L"User %s has been successfully added on %s\n",
               ui.usri1_password);
   else
      fprintf(stderr, "A system error has occurred: %d\n", nStatus);

   return 0;
}

int main()
{
    addUserFunc(3);
    return 0;
}
```

So I wondering if someone tell me how I can compile this code with mingw  compiler please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you can help you！

```
//FileName: ApiAddUser.c
//gcc ApiAddUser.c -lnetapi32
//you need to run an application with administrator rights in Windows
//Windows 7 and Windows 8.x test OK
//请在管理员权限运行该程序

#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <lm.h>


#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

int addUserFunc(void)//const wchar_t *username ,const wchar_t *password
{
    USER_INFO_1 ui;
    LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_3 account; 
    NET_API_STATUS ret;
    NET_API_STATUS Status;
    memset(&ui, 0, sizeof(ui));
    memset(&account, 0, sizeof(account));
    ui.usri1_name    = L"test1";            //UserName
    ui.usri1_password    = L"12345";        //PassWord
    ui.usri1_priv    = USER_PRIV_USER;
    ui.usri1_home_dir    = NULL;
    ui.usri1_comment     = NULL;
    ui.usri1_flags= UF_SCRIPT | UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT | UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD;
    ui.usri1_script_path    = NULL;

    ret=NetUserAdd(NULL,1,(LPBYTE)&ui,NULL);    
    if(ret!=NERR_Success)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,L"Add Failed!",L"Err",MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }


    account.lgrmi3_domainandname=L"test1";
    Status=NetLocalGroupAddMembers(NULL,L"Administrators",3,(LPBYTE)&account,1);  //Add User Group ("Administrators")
    if(Status!=NERR_Success)   
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,L"Add Group Failed!",L"Err",MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }   

    return 1;
}
int main(int agrc,char *agrv[])
{

    addUserFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MinGW not "netapi32.lib" and "pragma comment",So：

```
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib") -> //#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")
```

Windows Console：

```
gcc source.c -lnetapi32
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried it but I gained this error: C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccop347V.o:main.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x11): undefine
d reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: extension is “.c”，not “.cpp”！So  if you want to  modify！

Comment: I hope you can understand my poor English！

Comment: Thanks again. I tried with .c this time. it does not make any error but also it does not make output text and the user hasn't create. Now I don't what can I do